# How do I proxy make /x and /x/ point to the same place using nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy

So I've found multiple answers to this online, but none seem to work. Anyway, I have two services I'd like to use nginx as a proxy for. One is a gogs (a git server) and the other is a torrent daemon.

Now if I use the configuration below *without* the "rewrite" statements, then everything works at:

```
http://example.com/gogs/
http://example.com/torrent/
```

As you can see, it requires the trailing slash; if I forget it, both of them will hang during the request. This obviously isn't very desirable.

I've been playing with this statement I found in another post, which is supposed to rewrite any incoming URLs without a dot in them into their slash-terminated equivalent if they lack one.

```
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

However, it doesn't seem to do anything :(

Here is my nginx server block right now:

```
    server {

        listen       888;
        server_name  example.com;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

        rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

        location / {
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /git/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        }

        location /torrent/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9091;
        }
    }
```

So my question is, what have I done wrong? Changing the locations block URLs to their slashless form breaks everything.

Comment: Not clear what's wrong. By default nginx will redirect you from `/git` to `/git/` and from `/torrent` to `/torrent/`. If it's not, then there is something that prevent it from this. What shows `curl -v http://example.com:888/git` ?

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip! That revealed the problem; the machine this is running on is actually remapped to port 80 externally, so my request comes from http://example.com/git, and it tries to redirect me to http://example.com:888/git//, which is not externally visible. Is there a way to get it to rewrite its response to http://example.com/git/ instead?

Comment: `port_in_redirect off;` directive

Comment: Or you should configure whatever proxies port 80 to 888 to fix `Location` header in response